# Pandas wide to long by two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas in Python and want to transform a dataframe from wide to long while collapsing two columns. Specifically, I have a dataframe like this:

```
user   town    dog  cat
tom    london  1    1
dick   miami   0    1
harry  paris   0    0
tina   london  3    0
donna  dallas  0    1
hannah dallas  1    0
```

which I want to transform to a long table while collapsing `dogs` and `cats` into a category `pet`:

```
user   town    pets
tom    london  dog
tom    london  cat
dick   miami   cat
tina   london  dog
tina   london  dog
tina   london  dog
donna  dallas  cat
hannah dallas  dog
```

In R, it is possible to do this using the function `pivot_long` but I want to learn how to do it in Python using pandas. So far I have tried to use `pandas.melt(df, id_vars=['user', 'town'], value_vars=['dog', 'cat'])` but the output looks like:

```
user   town   variable  value
tom    london dog       1
tom    london cat       1
dick   miami  dog       0
dick   miami  cat       1
...
```

Comment: add `var_name='pets'` as a parameter to melt and just `.drop('value', axis=1)` afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do a little bit of pandas manipulation to get it in the format you want. But, this gives the output you are looking for:

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = [["tom", "london", 1, 1]
           ,["dick", "miami", 0, 1]
           ,["harry", "paris", 0, 0]
           ,["tina", "london", 3, 0]
           ,["donna", "dallas", 0, 1]
           ,["hannah", "dallas", 1, 0]]

    columns = ["user", "town", "dog", "cat"]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    long = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['user', 'town'], value_vars=['dog', 'cat'])
    long = long[long["value"] > 0]
    long = long.loc[long.index.repeat(long["value"])][["user", "town", "variable"]]
    print(long)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice solution +1

Answer (score 4):

`set_index` and `stack` the pet columns into a single Series. Renaming the columns axis brings that name along to the result. Then using `Series.repeat` you can get the required duplication as all the information is in the Index.

```
s = df.set_index(['user', 'town']).rename_axis(columns='pets').stack()

#df1 = s.repeat(s).reset_index().drop(columns=0)

# Credit @Scott Boston for this simpler version.
df1 = s.repeat(s).index.to_frame(index=False)
```

---

```
print(df1)
     user    town pets
0     tom  london  dog
1     tom  london  cat
2    dick   miami  cat
3    tina  london  dog
4    tina  london  dog
5    tina  london  dog
6   donna  dallas  cat
7  hannah  dallas  dog
```

Comment: Can I offer a simplier second line?  `s.repeat(s).index.to_frame(name=['users', 'town', 'pets'], index=False)`

Comment: @ScottBoston Good Idea. ALso changed to renaming the columns axis before the stack, which makes the repeats even simpler in either case.

Comment: Thanks, this is neat! +1
For information, Python returns the following error when I use this solution with certain rows (which, in my real dataset, contain users with e.g. emoji): 
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'LaughingMan''`

Comment: @psychcphyscst It seems that some of the values in your dog/cats columns are not numeric (or you have more columns that you're unknowingly stacking). If it's the latter make sure you only select `[['dog', 'cat']]` when you stack. If it's the former, after stacking do `s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')` to fix any bad values, then repeat

Comment: @ALollz, you are the champ +1 :-) dude.